# Submitting form via jquery trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I'm brand new to javascript and seriously cannot figure this out.

So, I have a button linked to a form that will submit the data gathered from the form. I was told to rewrite the JS/ JQuery so that it can work across a website.

```
button(trigger-submit='form-presentation').btn.btn-primary(
    name="action", 
    value="add-assessment"
    ) Save & Edit Assessment
```

is linked to

```
  form.form-presentation(
    action=route.seminar(seminar, 'create_presentation', {}, 'post'), 
    method="POST", 
    enctype="multipart/form-data"
  )
```

And here is the non-functioning JS:

```
define([
  'jquery',
], function ($) {

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('[trigger-submit]').click(function() {
      document.form-presentation.submit();
    });

  });
});
```

I have a feeling I need `data();` in there, but I don't know how it would work. I'm ready to tear my hair out from this. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received some help from someone and he helped me figure out the code I needed.

```
$($(this).attr('.trigger-submit')).submit();
```

Would work in this case, and would allow for it to be used across the site.